# Drop Down List Selection makes read only text box

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, textbox, html.dropdownlistfor

So the issue i am having is that depending on the specific injury that is selected from the drop down list ex: thigh, arm, head, heart, fingers. Certain text boxes will be read only. ex: if you select you pinky finger all text boxes will be read only except the digits text box. if shoulder is selected all text boxes will be read only except UE. and if thigh or knee is select then all text boxes will be read only except the LE text box.**

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  function jsFunction(sel){
    var expression = sel.value;
    
  switch(expression) {
      case "1":
          document.getElementById("txtLowerExtremity").readOnly = true;
          document.getElementById("txtUpperExtremity").readOnly = false;
          document.getElementById("txtDigits").readOnly = false;
          break;
      case "2":
          document.getElementById("txtLowerExtremity").readOnly = false;
          document.getElementById("txtUpperExtremity").readOnly = true;
          document.getElementById("txtDigits").readOnly = false;
          break;
      case "3":
          document.getElementById("txtLowerExtremity").readOnly = false;
          document.getElementById("txtUpperExtremity").readOnly = false;
          document.getElementById("txtDigits").readOnly = true;
          break;  
      case "4":
          document.getElementById("txtLowerExtremity").readOnly = false;
          document.getElementById("txtUpperExtremity").readOnly = false;
          document.getElementById("txtDigits").readOnly = false;
          break;
                    
      default:
          //do nothing
  } 
  }
</script>
```

```html
<asp:DropDownList ClientIDMode="Static" onChange="dropDownListSelection(sel)" ID="ddlImpairment" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Text="---- " Value="00.00.00.00" />
    <asp:ListItem Value="03.01.00.00" Text="03.01.00.00 [ ] Valvular Heart Disease" />
    <asp:ListItem Value="03.02.00.00" Text="03.02.00.00 [ ] Coronary Heart Disease" />
    <asp:ListItem Value="03.03.00.00" Text="03.03.00.00 [ ] Congenital Heart Disease" />
    <asp:ListItem Value="03.04.00.00" Text="03.04.00.00 [ ] Cardiomyopathies" />
    <asp:ListItem Value="03.05.00.00" Text="03.05.00.00 [ ] Pericardial Heart Disease" />
    <asp:ListItem Value="03.06.00.00" Text="03.06.00.00 [ ] Arrhythmia" />

    

<asp:ListItem Value="18.00.00.00" Text="18.00.00.00 [ ] Pain - use FEC rank for involved body part." />  </asp:DropDownList>



<asp:TextBox ID="txtUpperExtremity" MaxLength="2"  ClientIDMode="Static" Width="40px" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:TextBox ID="txtLowerExtremity" MaxLength="2" ClientIDMode="Static" Width="40px" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:TextBox name="txtDigits" MaxLength="2" ClientIDMode="Static" ID="txtDigits" Width="40px" runat="server">/asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: In your jsFunction, you test the selected value with `case "1"`, `case "2"`, etc. but the items in your list have values like `03.01.00.00`. How are these values supposed to match? Is it the first two digits that decide which controls must be readonly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a working solution for you.

```
<asp:DropDownList ClientIDMode="Static" onchange="javascript: jsFunction();" ID="ddlImpairment" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem Text="---- " Value="00.00.00.00" />
            <asp:ListItem Value="03.01.00.00" Text="03.01.00.00 [ ] Valvular Heart Disease" />
            <asp:ListItem Value="03.02.00.00" Text="03.02.00.00 [ ] Coronary Heart Disease" />
            <asp:ListItem Value="03.03.00.00" Text="03.03.00.00 [ ] Congenital Heart Disease" />
            <asp:ListItem Value="03.04.00.00" Text="03.04.00.00 [ ] Cardiomyopathies" />
            <asp:ListItem Value="03.05.00.00" Text="03.05.00.00 [ ] Pericardial Heart Disease" />
            <asp:ListItem Value="03.06.00.00" Text="03.06.00.00 [ ] Arrhythmia" />
            <asp:ListItem Value="18.00.00.00" Text="18.00.00.00 [ ] Pain - use FEC rank for involved body part." />
        </asp:DropDownList>



        <asp:TextBox ID="txtUpperExtremity" MaxLength="2" ClientIDMode="Static" Width="40px" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

        <asp:TextBox ID="txtLowerExtremity" MaxLength="2" ClientIDMode="Static" Width="40px" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

        <asp:TextBox name="txtDigits" MaxLength="2" ClientIDMode="Static" ID="txtDigits" Width="40px" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function jsFunction() {
        var expression = document.getElementById("ddlImpairment").selectedIndex;

        switch (expression) {
            case 1:
                document.getElementById("txtLowerExtremity").readOnly = true;
                document.getElementById("txtUpperExtremity").readOnly = false;
                document.getElementById("txtDigits").readOnly = false;
                break;
            case 2:
                document.getElementById("txtLowerExtremity").readOnly = false;
                document.getElementById("txtUpperExtremity").readOnly = true;
                document.getElementById("txtDigits").readOnly = false;
                break;
            case 3:
                document.getElementById("txtLowerExtremity").readOnly = false;
                document.getElementById("txtUpperExtremity").readOnly = false;
                document.getElementById("txtDigits").readOnly = true;
                break;
            case 4:
                document.getElementById("txtLowerExtremity").readOnly = false;
                document.getElementById("txtUpperExtremity").readOnly = false;
                document.getElementById("txtDigits").readOnly = false;
                break;

            default:
                //do nothing
        }
    }
</script>
```

Let me know if you need any further help.